# Two conditions in regular expressions with python

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why the first item of my output is empty and not "@stackoverflow"

```
import re
s = "I love @stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"
re.findall(r"@|#(\w+)" , s)
```

output:

```
['', 'people', 'helpful']
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `r"@|#(\w+)"` is the same as `r"(?:@)|(?:#(\w+))"`, so your regex looks for either a hash symbol followed by something or an "at" symbol *alone*.

Your code returns exactly what's expected:

- the first part of the regex doesn't have any capture groups, so it matches the "@" and returns an empty string.
- the second part does have a match group and returns that

To match "stackoverflow" in "@stackoverflow", try this:

```
>>> re.findall("[@#](\w+)", s)
['stackoverflow', 'people', 'helpful']
```

This is the same as specifying the precedence explicitly:

```
>>> re.findall("(?:@|#)(\w+)", s)
['stackoverflow', 'people', 'helpful']
```

`"(?:@|#)(\w+)"` means:
 * match either "@" or "#", but do not capture it
 * if the above matched, match `(\w+)` and capture the result, because `(...)` is a capturing group

In the context of `re.findall`, only capturing groups will appear in the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

Because it uses it as `"@"` or `"#(\w+)"`. Try:

```
re.findall(r"[@#](\w+)" , s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your regex is being interpreted as [match just `@`, or `#` with some `\w` after it, and capture only the `\w`s], you can use this regex instead to get both symbols along with what's after them:

```
import re
s = "I love @stackoverflow because #people are very #helpful!"
print(re.findall(r"[@#]\w+" , s))
```

Output:

```
['@stackoverflow', '#people', '#helpful']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the pattern `@|#(\w+)` matches either the pattern:

`@`

or

`#(\w+)`

and when it matches the first side of the `|`, the pattern is not capturing anything.

You could fix this by using the pattern `[@#](\w+)`.